# Navigation Bar set to be invisible, but when back button is clicked it appears

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

As the title indicates, the root view is my navigation controller, and it is set to be invisible, which it is on launch. However if I push a view onto the stack and then pop it the navigation bar appears.

Any clues as to why and how to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide it every time yours controller's `view` appears (or disappears) on screen. This is necessary since the bar maintains the state among differents push/pop operations. For example, if you have set it hidden in `viewDidLoad` within in first controller and in the second one you set it visible, when you pop the second controller the bar mantains the last state you have set.

For example override `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods and hide/unhide the bar there.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];    
}    

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];    
}
```